# UIPageViewController prevent hiding keyboard on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I have a `UIPageViewController` with multiple `UIViewController`, each one containing a `UITextField`.

Whenever I slide the `UIPageViewController`, the keyboard automatically dismisses. Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Invoking `becomeFirstResponder` on the new `UITextfield` but the animation the won't fix the problem.

Comment: `textFieldShouldReturn:` is called when you hit the enter key. There is no reason it should be called when scrolling.

Comment: Just a thought but have you tried overriding `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` in your view controllers? Not sure if this would be causing the issue but worth a try.

Comment: @Dima `disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal` doesn't fix!

Comment: Can you upload a sample project that showcases this issue onto Github or something? Would help to be able to take a look at the code.

Comment: Sample Project by Apple: [link](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B48GYnn-LJzZcjhRQ3ptTzJMX1E&usp=sharing)

Comment: Using **UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl** instead of **UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll** doesn't dismiss the keyboard. Maybe the problem is related to the scroll animation.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to embed the PageViewController as a ChildViewController of an other viewController.

I believe this way the navigation in the PageViewController will not effect the keyboard.
I am not sure if that is needed, but if it is still not working you can set your ParentViewController as the firstResponder when transition occurs.

Comment: @PGLongo any solution for this?

Comment: At the end I've used [BWWalkthrough](https://github.com/ariok/BWWalkthrough) and changed the firstResponder in `walkthroughPageDidChange`

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately this seems to come from the animation of the transition showing as done, before it is actually done,
the workarounds I can think of are
1. made the animating false
2. set textFieldShouldEndEditing in the next VC to return NO or handle it with a bool
3. add a delay in the animation, or in the next VC viewWillAppear

Answer (score 0):

When using `setViewControllers` on `UIPageViewController` (setting a controller without the scroll), it seems that the completion block is called just before the `scrollView` has reached its final position. When it does, it dismisses the first responder.

The solution we found was to first, grab the scroll view:

```
// In UIPageViewController subclass
for subview in self.view.subviews {

    if let scrollV = subview as? UIScrollView {
        scrollV.delegate = self
        self.scrollView = scrollV // Optional, we don't really need it
    }

}
```

The scroll view position is done when its `offset` is the `x` position of the middle controller. That is, the `offset` will equal the view's length.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if scrollView.contentOffset.x == self.view.width {
        // Transition is 'really' done.
    }
}
```

At that point, you can send a notification that transition is completed.
What we did, is hold a completion block and call it when the transition is done.

Create a function, so that a controller can pass a block in:

```
func transitionCompleted(completed:(()->())?) {
        self.transitionCompletedBlock = completed
}
```

When transition is completed:

```
self.transitionCompletedBlock?()
```

The controller with the keyboard will look like:

```
pagerController.transitionCompleted(completed: {
            self.textfield.becomeFirstResponder()
})
```